# How to add another Add To Cart and product variant selection in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

How can I add another add to cart button as well as product variant selection above product description in my Woocommerce product page?

Comment: Which product description?  The short or main one?

Comment: The short description

Answer (score 0):

This will add another variable product selector above the short description.  For simple products they will remain unchanged.  This code was taken from the function **woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart** which I have basically copied and just removed the **wp_enqueue_script** call as this is already included in the usual variation selector already present.  Paste this code into your theme's **functions.php** file.

```
function add_product_variation_selector() {
    global $product;

    // Enqueue variation scripts.
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) :
        // Get Available variations?
        $get_variations = count( $product->get_children() ) <= apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 30, $product );

        // Load the template.
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
            'available_variations' => $get_variations ? $product->get_available_variations() : false,
            'attributes'           => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
            'selected_attributes'  => $product->get_default_attributes(),
        ) );
    endif;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_product_variation_selector', 9 );
```

Comment: This code added another add to cart button and variation selector right above the current one instead of adding it at the top of short description.

Comment: It might depend on what theme you are using.  I've changed the priority of the hook above to 9 and it's still appearing above the short description on the 2017 default theme.

Answer (score -2):

Clone the `plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php` to your theme following the instructions from the file.
Change it according to your needs.

Comment: No this is not the best way of doing it, use hooks.

Comment: For me it's better to write layout code with all the DIVS in layout file.

Comment: Hooks and filters are the preferred method for future proofing your website against upgrades.